# Failed to load resource in webstorm

Tags: webstorm

I just downloaded the trial version of WebStorm and tried out [jQuery boilerplate demo](https://github.com/jquery-boilerplate/jquery-boilerplate) on it.

If i use "Open page in browser" everything gets loaded fine and i get the `console.log("xD"`) just fine. However if I try to debug this using Chrome I get this:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)  js\jquery.boilerplate.js:24
    js\jquery.boilerplate.js:24
    js\jquery.boilerplate.js:43
```

I have the JetBrains addon installed in Chrome and i've pointed the debugger to the index.html file.

Can anyone tell me what i'm missing here?

Comment: works fine for me - just downloaded the demo, opened it in WebStorm 7.0.1 and right-clicked the demo/index.html to debug. here is what is printed to console: xD src\jquery.boilerplate.js:41
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)  http://localhost:63342/jquery-boilerplate-master/src/jquery.boilerplate.js.map:0

Comment: i.e. the resource is loade, console.log prints the expected info. The 404 message is just the debug output: the Jetbrains IDE Chrome extension checks for presence of js.map files, and, if not found, prints a message. The reason for this checking is that some tools used to compress/transpile code don't generate required //sourceMapUrl comment the debugger needs to locate sourcemaps, so it checks some default locations for maps presence. So, these messages don't indicate any errors and don't do any harm, they can be safely ignored.